# How to detect a Scikit-learn warning programmatically

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn

While fitting a model using [`sklearn.neural_network.MLPClassifier`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neural_network.MLPClassifier.html) I sometimes receive a warning printed in the console:

> ConvergenceWarning: Stochastic Optimizer: Maximum iterations (300) reached and the optimization hasn't converged yet.

Is there a way to detect the warning during runtime so I can act on it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can catch the warning in realtime with [`warnings.catch_warnings`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html#warnings.catch_warnings)

```
import warnings

with warnings.catch_warnings():
    warnings.filterwarnings('error')
    try:
        model.fit(X, y)
    except Warning:
        # do something in response
```

This structure will catch any Warning in line and allow you to respond to it however you see fit. In this case that may be modifying some hyperparameter to make it easier for the model to converge.

You can also ignore warnings with [`warnings.filterwarnings`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html#warnings.filterwarnings) and can specify the type of warning to ignore.

To ignore `ConvergenceWarning`:

```
from sklearn.exceptions import ConvergenceWarning

...

warnings.filterwarnings('ignore', category=ConvergenceWarning)

...
```

Comment: Is the warning a part of the API? The docs do not seem to give any guarantee that the warning will remain the same throughout versions, so this approach seems a bit fragile to me.

Comment: missing a semicolon at the end of the "with" line ?

Comment: Two issues with this answer: (1) The 'with' line should end in a colon. (2) Use of 'warnings.filterwarnings('error')' turns the warning into an Exception, so the catch clause 'except Warning' doesn't work. It should be 'except Exception'.

Comment: @JerryK. It should raise a Warning according to [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html#the-warnings-filter). `Since the Warning class is derived from the built-in Exception class, to turn a warning into an error we simply raise category(message).` And in the `sklearn` example, it should raise the `ConvergenceWarning` as it is set as the category.

Answer (score 2):

Check the `n_iter_` attribute after fitting. If it is less than the maximum number of iterations you configured (`max_iter`), then it converged.

Comment: from which object/class can you within the block obtain `n_iter`? some code would help.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. For example AffinityPropagation could early stop, give a warning and return some arbitrary result without actual converging.

Comment: `assert model.n_iter_ < MAX_ITER, "Convergence failed!"`

Answer (score 1):

Let's say that you want to train your scikit-learn model and you want to be able to store the warnings (if any).
Let's say that you fit the model as follows:

`clf.fit(X_train, y)`

If you want to catch the warning. Then you can run the model:

```
with warnings.catch_warnings(record=True) as caught_warnings:
    clf.fit(X_train, y)
```

Finally, you can get the warnings by iterating the `caught_warnings` as follows:

```
for warn in caught_warnings:
    print(warn)
```